# NACK vs. ACK? When to use one over the other one?

Tags: protocol-theory

Personally I don't even feel that there is a need for ACK. It's faster if we just send NACK(n) for the lost packets instead of sending an ACK for each received packet. So when/which situations would one use ACK over NACK and viceversa?

Comment: Could you give us some more context for what you're talking about?  Are you asking generically, or about TCP, or??

Comment: A General networking question not related to TCP, UDP or any other specific area.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The reason for the ACK is that a NACK is simply not sufficient.  Let's say I send you a data stream of X segments (let's say 10 for simplicity).

You are on a bad connection, and only receive segments 1, 2, 4, and 5.  Your computer sends the NACK for segment 3, but doesn't realize there should be segments 6-10 and does not NACK those.

So, I resend segment 3, but then my computer falsely believes the data is successfully sent.

ACKs provide some assurance that the segment has arrived at the destination.

If you want the application to deal with order of data and retransmissions, you can simply choose to utilize a protocol like UDP (for instance, like TFTP does).

Comment: Good answer. But couldn't we just designate the first packet as a special packet - it would include the number of segments it would send.

Comment: That still leaves the problem of the sender not knowing if the data is received. With no ACK in the process, if the sender doesn't hear anything back it will just have to assume all the data was received, even if the entire flow of data were lost. The ACK assures that the data was received.

Answer (score 4):

It all boils down to the loss probability distribution and traffic pattern.

Take for example a typical wireless link, with a steady 10-30% loss rate. If you ack each received frame (like 802.11abg), you will quickly detect when a frame has been lost, so you will not loose time to wait for a timeout.

If you were to NAK instead, you will become dependent on the traffic pattern:
- If you send a single request packet and expect an answer, and that request is lost, you will have to have a timeout that expires if you do not get an answer.
- If you are just sending a stream of packet to a mostly mute recipient, then it is acceptable to only receive a NAK when the recipient receives the next packet or so. But this mean that the recipient has to reorder packets and that the sender must keep track of a large backlog of messages that it has sent.

(guess what solution 802.11n choose ? both.  The receiver sends a variable-length bitmap of frames that it has received)

Now take a typical Internet network: You have close to 0% packet loss, until something bad happens, and you have a close to 100% packet loss for a certain time following some exponential distribution law, from a 200ms interruption to a minute and a half.

Acking each packet would seem pointless in a non-lossy network, until you consider the case when the link is severed: you will not receive ACK or NACK for a possibly extended amount of time, and the receiver will typically not send anything until the link is restored.

If you use ACK, the sender will stop sending and keep its backlog until the link is restored. If you use NACK instead, then the receiver may eventually tell you that it has not received the packet that fell off the sender's backlog since a long time, and the connection is essentially unrecoverable.

Answer (score 1):

ACKs are useful in sliding window protocols, they allow Transmitter A to be aware that data sent has been received by remote B. Transmitter A can then proceed to send next data - until its transmit window is full (of data sent to remote but not yet acknowledged).

ACKs may be considered more essential than NAKs. NAKs simply allow for *faster recovery*, in the case where a packet/block sent by A is not received by B, and B detects by some way that a packet/block is missing.

It is perfectly feasible to design a protocol supporting reliable transfer and flow control only with ACK, **without NAK** (with retransmission by Transmitter in case Transmitter does not receive an ACK, retransmission mechanism that is needed in any case).

Answer (score 0):

One most important thing i would like to add here, in TCP, we DO NOT sent ACK for EVERY RECEIVED PACKET.

However, the ACKs are sent only for the LAST RECEIVED PACKET.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: This is true up to a point. For instance, segments with only the ACK or RST flag set do not require an ACK. Additionally, if delayed ACKs are in use, then there may not be an ACK every segment, however generally this requires that an ACK be sent for every other segment. Yet many TCP connections will not use delayed ACKs and will send an ACK for every segment carrying data.